# how to display the driving routes

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps

I am developing an app with which, the user can input the destination and a route from his current position to the destination will be shown on the google map.
I searched online and found many tutorials in which they were using google map api javascript v3 . I also read the official documents from

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

But I am confused as

- how are they using  the javascript in their program.
- how is  XML /JSON   working.
- how is this program overall is working?

As what I understand that the methods defined in the above documents are related to  a browser app, so how will it be launched from an android application?

And finally which is the best way/method/api to develop this  app.

Lastly , I am not looking for the code ,as I will develop the code myself. I am just wanted to know that overall how these app/ google maps is working?

Thanks

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) have tutorial to draw route path on map in our app. this may help you and
use below to link with map app... this will take to you in google map application

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="+source_latitude+","+source_longitude+"&daddr="+destination_latitude+","+destination_longitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: does the source_latitude/longitude and the destination_latitude/longitude needs to be constant or  the user can enter these values in a text box and I can replace the    source_latitude/longitude and the destination_latitude/longitude with the user's value?

Comment: for these 4 variable you have to pass value for it.

Comment: will it work, if the user enters name of the cities instead of the coordinates?