# Draw path in Google Map like A to B then B to C then C to D . like that

Tags: android, google-maps

I just displayed a path between to locations in Google Map using this code.

```
   double srclat=8.8854;
   double srclong=76.5833;
   double destlat=9.0544;
   double destlong=76.5353;

  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com /maps?saddr="+srclat+","+srclong+"&daddr="+destlat+","+destlong));
    startActivity(i);
```

Now I wan to know that can I draw path in Google Map like A to B then B to C then C to D.  using this method or something like this

Thanks in advance

Comment: use google map api v2. use the polylines to draw path between points. check the link @ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes

Comment: @Raghunandan I refer the above link. now it shows that :    
     

     05-25 06:39:30.751: E/dalvikvm(1906): Could not find class       'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions', referenced       from method com.eple.router.MainActivity.onCreate

, but I already imported the required packages.

Comment: Now the above code is not working.. please help..

Comment: Now it's working but can't draw path between multiple locations..

Comment: @Anandhu - do you want to show driving routes?

Comment: @Anandhu this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563098/show-routes-between-multiple-points-on-google-maps

Comment: @RachelGallen  Yes, driving routes.

Comment: @Anandhu you can draw paths between multiple location using polylines. but you need to modify the code accordingly

Comment: @Raghunandan When I trying to use the Polylines and MapFragment. It shows an exception in logcat like The com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment can't be located . But I already included the google play services.

Comment: @Anandhu can u post the code and the logcar for further assistance. Also did you update adt to rev 22?

Comment: @Anandhu how did you refer google play services library in your android project. If you follow the steps correctly in the link you should be able to get the map

Answer (score 0):

I can draw Google Map Polyline using these steps :

1. Implement Google Map v2 on Android (obviously)
2. Get the JSON response from google directions API from this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json (try googling a few documentations or examples),

   Specify the starting lat-long and destination lat-long, for example :
   [Follow this link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-7.7483675,110.3487879&destination=-7.7468831562644604,110.34991309046745&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving), the result is a JSON response, and you can read it online using [This JSON Formatter](http://bodurov.com/jsonformatter)
3. Parse the JSON response, it has a JSON Object called `overview polyline`, which contains the polyline data that you need to draw.
4. Grab the `points` data inside `overview_polyline`
5. Draw polyline using this method :

   `Map.addPolyline(new polylineOptions().addAll(decodePolyLine(polyline)))`

If implemented correctly, you should be able to draw a polyline successfully.
Please do try to read some documentations, it does help :)

Good luck ^^